# What means "To be drafted with something"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

What means "To be drafted with something"?

Could it mean to be distracted or deviated or forced to do an undesired thing?

I used this phrase to say when one is doing something may be drafted with something else.

For example when writing a paper, one may be drafted with finding the proper word.

Is it a proper usage of the phrase?

**Update:** I think I confused draft with **drift**, if drift convey the meaning please let me know

Comment: No, it's an incorrect usage. *Correct* (but a bit starchy/formal) would be *He was **charged** with finding the proper word* (equivalent to *He was **commanded/instructed** to find it*). Alternatively, *He was **drafted in/conscripted** to find it* - figuratively alluding to military conscription (and meaning that he was taken away from his normal job, and forced to work on this new word search).

Answer (score 2):

You're using *draft* very incorrectly.

*Draft* is a noun that means "first run-work," and it can be a verb meaning "to make a technical drawing" or "make a first run-work."  *With* afterward would generally qualify how you are making the draft, i.e. *I am drafting the project on a computer using AutoCAD.*

*Draft* can also mean "conscripted into the military" and in that case a *with {person}* afterward makes sense: *I was drafted in the Korean War with my buddy, who I still talk to this day.*

It never means "distracted."

Comment: "Drafted" can also be used in the second sense metaphorically, to say that one was forced to join some group or do some job. "Forced" here could mean ordered by a boss, compelled by social pressure, etc. In that sense it could sort of mean a distraction. Like, "I was trying to finish project X when I was drafted to work on project Y." The OPs phrasing is incorrect, but perhaps he heard someone else use the word in that sense and that's where he's getting the idea.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, [_drafting_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drafting_(aerodynamics)) is also a technical term in cycling and other racing sports.

Comment: @Jay Thanks, I meant something similar, then it has the meaning and it seems is used with "to"? what is wrong with my phrasing?

Comment: One word may have many meanings, I asked if it has a meaning close to what I meant. it seems being forced or deviated ... could be the answer

Comment: If you are forced/"conscripted" to do something, you are drafted *for* it, not drafted *with* it.

Comment: I suppose in your example you could say -- note, NOT a good example, a strained example -- "While working on this paper, I was drafted into a search for a word meaning X." But this would be a bad example because when we use "drafted" in this sense we normally talk about being drafted onto some unrelated task, not getting bogged down in a detail of this task. You might well say, "While I was trying to work on this paper, I was drafted into helping clean the office." If you were talking about a detail of the task itself, it would be better to say, "I was distracted by ..." ...

Comment: ... or "I was sidetracked by ..." or "I got bogged down in ..."

Comment: Maybe what I've heard was **drift**, could that be applicable in my sentences?

Comment: You can think of *drift* as meaning *to passively float toward something,* such as on water.  *Drift with X* sounds very odd unless you mean two things drifting toward something together.  Typically you can *drift to* something or *drift toward* something.